Had a Parasitic Drain from car stereo. Problem went away spontaneously. Why?
Had a Parasitic Drain coming from car stereo, Boss Audio Systems BCPA9.
Car is a Scion tC, 2005.
I know it was the stereo because the display screen stayed lit after removing the keys from ignition, which it never used to do before.
After a couple  days of dead battery overnight, I started disconnecting the negative battery terminal until the next morning, intending to investigate/ resolve the problem later when I had more time.
Last night I didn't disconnect the negative terminal, and it looks like the problem has resolved itself.
Display screen no longer stays lit when I remove the keys.
What could be going on in a situation like this?

What is the year/make/model of the vehicle the audio system is in?

Car is a SCION tC  , year 2005.
